# Sufficient condition for graph isomorphism

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Let $G,H$ be graphs on vertices $V(G)$ and $V(H)$ respectively. Let $f:V(G)\to V(H)$ be a bijection which preserves vertex degree i.e
$$\forall u\in V(G)\left (\deg _Gu=\deg _Hf(u)\right ) $$
Is this sufficient for $G\cong H$?

Since degrees are preserved, it must mean there are equally many edges, since the sum of degrees is exactly twice the number of edges.

Does the same $f$ fit the bill, then? Is $\{u,v\}\in E(G)$ equivalent to $\{f(u),f(v)\}\in E(H)$? NOPE!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider the cycle graph $C_6$, and the disjoint union of two cycle graphs $C_3 \sqcup C_3$. Both have six vertices of degree 2, but they are not isomorphic.

Comment: Great, thanks! :) Suppose we modify the original problem with: Let G,H be connected, that would still preserve the number of edges and there's a bijection between the edges, hence perhaps we have a hope of obtaining an isomorphism?

Comment: No. There are still counterexamples. Consider the Petersen graph and two concentric circles centered on some origin with 5 vertices each on them. Adjoin the vertices on different circles which pass through the same ray through the origin.

Comment: No, more generally there are graphs with the same degree sequence. For instance, there are many regular graphs - such as the cubic graphs (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicGraph.html). Even stronger, there can be sets of graphs with the same "extended" degree - that is, they have the same degree sequence and vertices with the same degree in each graph have neighbours with the same degree.

Comment: @AlvinLepik, for a really simple example: connect the two triangles of $C_3 \sqcup C_3$ by a single edge; and add any edge to $C_6$.